# find content is not working when scraping html using php

Tags: php, html

I am tying to scrape html content of a web page using php. I am doing to achieve this like

```
$url = 'http://listing.hire4tech.com/';
$html = file_get_html($url);
```

When i am displaying the html using like this

```
echo $html;
```

Html is displaying perfectly but when i am scraping content using below

```
$activelink = $html->find('div#nav_menu_list ul li.active a', 0)->plaintext;
```

When i am displaying the title using the code below

```
echo $activelink; die();
```

This is not giving me anythink. I am using ubuntu 18.04.2 with xampp. When i am trying the same in my friend's laptop, this is displaying correctly. What is the issue ?

Comment: Is this that find function is restricted or something else because same thing is working to others ?

Comment: What is the type of your $html variable ?

Comment: what do you mean by type here ?

Comment: Your $html variable is an object of which class ? What does return the function file_get_html() ?

Comment: function returns html page of url.

Comment: php does contains a function named `file_get_html`, if you use any 3rd party library, you need mention it.

Comment: no i am not using any third party library, flie_get_html is working fine though. Issue is that $html->find is not working.

Comment: You seem to use [Simple HTML DOM](https://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/simple-php-html-dom_pc). What is the output of `echo $html;` ?